# What are white spots on the fingernails, caused by leukonychia, colloquially called?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image: LKeukonychia]

My mother used to call them "presents". Indeed she had a little rhyme that went:

Present on the finger,
Sure to linger.
Present on the thumb,
Sure to come.

Has anyone else ever heard that? And what do others call them? Is there an everyday term? *Leukonychia* is the medical name, but it seems far too elaborate to teach to a child.

Comment: Uh, "white spots"??

Comment: We used to call them "lie spots" - and check each other's fingers to see who told the most lies. (1960's -'70's US)

Comment: Would the person who voted to close the question have the common courtesy to explain why?

Comment: [Lincolnshire dialect?](https://books.google.com/books?id=M_xKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=Present+on+the+finger,+Sure+to+linger.+Present+on+the+thumb,+Sure+to+come.&source=bl&ots=TXC7wwqfJt&sig=ACfU3U1pbxokIuMGU15Q2ZvLkVnuHBXAGw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKjtjqyOHpAhU1JDQIHdgHBhUQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=Present%20on%20the%20finger%2C%20Sure%20to%20linger.%20Present%20on%20the%20thumb%2C%20Sure%20to%20come.&f=false). Search without quotes: **Present on the finger, Sure to linger. Present on the thumb, Sure to come.** Also try searching: **white spots on nails folklore**

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thanks, so it mat well be known across the UK. If you would care to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -4):

From [Definition.com](https://www.definitions.net/definition/Leukonychia):

> *Leukonychia* Leukonychia, also known as **white nails** or **milk spots**, is a medical term for white discoloration appearing on nails.
>   It is derived from the Greek words leuko and onux. The most common
>   cause is injury to the base of the nail where the nail is formed. It
>   is harmless and most commonly caused by minor injuries that occur
>   while the nail is growing. Contrary to popular belief, leukonychia is
>   not a sign of excess or deficiency of calcium and zinc or other
>   vitamins in the diet. It is more commonly found on fingernails than
>   toenails. There is no effective treatment for leukonychia. However,
>   the white marks and spots gradually disappear as the nail grows
>   outward from the matrix with the nail plate.

Comment: Yeah, we used to call them "milk spots" sometimes, too. US

Comment: Had you ever heard them called "presents", @Edwin - and perhaps the rhyme I mentioned? Or is that unique to Norfolk?

Comment: Never. And I've never really given them more than a second's thought. Blood blisters, though, I do remember being concerned about, until I discovered they always progressed upnail until they flipped out after a month or so. _Unique to Norfolk_? I thought that was just Turkysh and windpumps. But there must be equally quirky usages in say Suffolk, the Home Counties ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well someone's identified a Lincolnshire instance. So perhaps just unique to the east coast. That would be unusual since Lincs belongs culturally and linguistically to the north, while Norfolk has more in common with Hampshire than it does with its neighbours across The Wash.